# Regex to test whether a string contains a phrase, with no extra alphanumberic characters on either side?

Tags: regex

For example let's say my phrase is "apples and oranges"

These strings should return a match:

"I like apples and oranges a lot"
"apples and oranges are good for you"
"You're comparing apples and oranges"
"apples and oranges."

These strings should not return a match:
"I like cranapples and oranges"
"apples and orangesherbert"

Answer (score 0):

```
/\bapples and oranges\b/
```

`\b` matches a word boundary.

> Matches a zero-width boundary between a word-class character (see
>   next) and either a non-word class character or an edge; same as
>   (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W).

An edge being beginning (`^`) or end (`$`) of string, and non-word being anything that matches `\W` (non-alphanumeric).